# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje de éxito de formulario enviado sin re-direccionar en PHP?

Tags: php, formularios

Tengo este pequeño código implementando un formulario de contacto en PHP:

```
<?php
//Recibimos los campos del formulario
$name=$_POST[name];
$organization=$_POST[organization];
$email=$_POST[email];
$phone=$_POST[phone];
$subject=$_POST[subject];
$message=$_POST[message];
//Acomodamos todo para darle orden al cuerpo del mensaje
$text_message="El usuario ".$name." perteneciente a la empresa ".$organization. " dijo: \n".$message." \n
Puedes contactarlo a su correo: \n".$email." \n o a su teléfono: ".$phone;
mail("tumail@mail.com",$subject,$text_message);
echo "Su mensaje se ha enviado! Nos pondremos en contacto contigo.";
?>
```

El segmento de html del formulario es el siguiente:

```
<section class="probootstrap-section probootstrap-bg-white">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 probootstrap-animate" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
            <form action="enviar.php" method="POST" class="probootstrap-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="organization">Organization</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization" name="organization">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-ghost" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-1 probootstrap-animate" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
```

Cuando completo los datos y hago click en enviar me redirecciona a /enviar.php

Quisiera que simplemente aparezca un mensaje de éxito en la misma página donde se encuentra el formulario en vez de redireccionar. Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias!

Comment: Buenas, el codigo no tiene que ir como imagenes, mismo caso los errores.

Comment: Hazlo con ajax.

Comment: Pega el codigo como texto, asi es mas facil ayudarte y no tener que escribir todo.

Comment: Edité la publicación para subir el código como texto.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar la misma página para procesar el formulario. Para eso tendrías que pegar el código al principio de esa página con alguna condición para determinar si se ha enviado el formulario.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST[name];
        ...
        echo "Su mensaje se ha enviado! Nos pondremos en contacto contigo.";
    }
?>
```

y direccionar el `action` del form a la misma página (o dejarlo en blanco)

```
<form action="" method...
```

Lo anterior no redirecciona **pero provoca que la pagina se cargue nuevamente**. Si lo que quieres ese evitar que la página se refresque, debes usar [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).

**Para el uso de ajax** (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) hay varias alternativas, si ya usas algún framework como jQuery, sería algo así:

```
var form = $('form')[0];
var fData = new FormData(form);
$.post('enviar.php', fData, function(data){
    //data es lo que responde el script de php, por ejemplo podrías mostrar el mensaje en un alert:
    alert(data);
})
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero estaría bien incluir una opción sin _jQuery_ como [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch). Siendo quisquilloso, también evitaría proporcionar enlaces de w3schools, no siempre tienen contenido actualizado. +1

Comment: Claro, gracias por la sugerencia, solo daba un ejemplo, soluciones posibles hay muchas.